# Is there any limit of complexity for Tweepy "search_tweets" query?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, named-entity-recognition

I want to get Tweets in this way:

```py
tweepy.Cursor(api.search_tweets, q=query, geocode=geo).items(limit), unit="tw", total=limit)
```

This goes to the api `search tweets` function and gets a limit of tweets with a specific
geolocation and query:

```py
limit = 1,
geo = "40.416755,-3.703790,500km",
query = Ayuso OR Imperio OR Álex Vicente OR Darwin OR Laura Pintos OR Casemiro OR José Luis Cortés OR Cristina G Bolinches OR Centro de Control de Defensa Nacional OR Pedro Águeda OR Carlos Marcos Sopelana OR Annunziata Murgia OR ABC PREMIUM OR LUCAS SÁEZ BRAVO OR Carlota Fominaya OR Esther López OR Mariano Peyrou OR Ancelotti OR Julián Quirós OR Manuel P Villatoro
```

length of query is 359, so it is less than 500 (that is Tweepy´s limit query length)

Is the query too complex for Tweepy API to get? Or am I missing something?
The query is obtained by donwloading newspapers text and passing a NER model to detect
popular entities in that day.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Is the query not working, are you getting an error? Are you able to use the query (the words, without the geo part) in the Twitter web search interface? Do you get any results?

Comment: Hello! I am not getting any error and yes, it enables me to use de query. When I print the Tweets that are supposed to be extracted, there are no Tweets. So I am not getting any results.

Comment: Can you edit the question to share more complete code (see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)). Is there anything in the data returned from `tweepy.Cursor`? How are you printing it out?